# Hel with SOAP request from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, soap

Hi there guy's i need to fetch data froma SOAP webservice. Here is an example:

```
POST /b2b.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: webservice.presstours.it
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <TtiPackageCosting xmlns="http://webservice.presstours.it/">
      <TTI_PkgCostRQ EchoToken="string" TimeStamp="dateTime" Target="" Version="decimal" TransactionIdentifier="string" SequenceNmbr="nonNegativeInteger" TransactionStatusCode="" ReqRespVersion="string" ActionType="Book or Quote or Hold or Initiate or Ignore or Modify or Commit or Cancel or CommitOverrideEdits or VerifyPrice or Ticket" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <POS>
          <Source AgentSine="string" PseudoCityCode="string" ISOCountry="string" ISOCurrency="string" AgentDutyCode="string" AirlineVendorID="string" AirportCode="string" FirstDepartPoint="string" ERSP_UserID="string" TerminalID="string">
            <RequestorID xsi:nil="true" />
            <Position xsi:nil="true" />
            <BookingChannel xsi:nil="true" />
          </Source>
          <Source AgentSine="string" PseudoCityCode="string" ISOCountry="string" ISOCurrency="string" AgentDutyCode="string" AirlineVendorID="string" AirportCode="string" FirstDepartPoint="string" ERSP_UserID="string" TerminalID="string">
            <RequestorID xsi:nil="true" />
            <Position xsi:nil="true" />
            <BookingChannel xsi:nil="true" />
          </Source>
        </POS>
        <ProvisionalID ExpiryDateTime="string" />
        <PackageRequest ID="string" Type="string" TravelCode="string" TourCode="string" BoardCode="string" PromotionCode="string" FreeChildrenQuantity="integer" BrandCode="string" ProductCode="string" AvailabilityInfo="Available or Unavailable or OnRequest or Confirmed">
          <URL ShareSynchInd="" ShareMarketInd="" Type="string" DefaultInd="boolean" />
          <CompanyName CompanyShortName="string" TravelSector="string" Code="string" CodeContext="string" Division="string" Department="string" />
          <DateRange Start="string" Duration="string" End="string" />
          <ItineraryItems>
            <ItineraryItem xsi:nil="true" />
            <ItineraryItem xsi:nil="true" />
          </ItineraryItems>
          <Extras>
            <Extra xsi:nil="true" />
            <Extra xsi:nil="true" />
          </Extras>
        </PackageRequest>
        <PassengerListItems>
          <PassengerListItem RPH="string" Telephone="string" TelephoneSpecified="boolean" Email="string" EmailSpecified="boolean" InsuranceRPH="string" Gender="" Nationality="string" BirthDate="date" LeadCustomerInd="boolean" Age="integer" Code="string" CodeContext="string" URI="anyURI">
            <Name xsi:nil="true" />
            <SpecialNeed xsi:nil="true" />
            <SpecialNeed xsi:nil="true" />
            <PassportInformation xsi:nil="true" />
          </PassengerListItem>
          <PassengerListItem RPH="string" Telephone="string" TelephoneSpecified="boolean" Email="string" EmailSpecified="boolean" InsuranceRPH="string" Gender="" Nationality="string" BirthDate="date" LeadCustomerInd="boolean" Age="integer" Code="string" CodeContext="string" URI="anyURI">
            <Name xsi:nil="true" />
            <SpecialNeed xsi:nil="true" />
            <SpecialNeed xsi:nil="true" />
            <PassportInformation xsi:nil="true" />
          </PassengerListItem>
        </PassengerListItems>
        <Extras>
          <Extra />
          <Extra />
        </Extras>
        <TPA_Extensions>xml</TPA_Extensions>
      </TTI_PkgCostRQ>
    </TtiPackageCosting>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

i'm trying to make this call in Laravel using package laravel-soap but i'm unable to make request asw well. Can someone tell me a method to make request as well? Actually i use this code to try to fect results but i got error "Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

```
    function show() 
  {
    $wrapper = new \Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\SoapWrapper();

    $service = $wrapper->add('Presstours', function ($service) {
    $service->wsdl('http://webservice.presstours.it/b2b.asmx?WSDL')
            ->cache(WSDL_CACHE_NONE)
            ->trace(true);
});

$data = 
[
  "TTI_PkgCostRQ"=>[
    "POS" => [
      "Source" => [
        "RequestorID" => [ 
          "ID" => "ZZZZZZZZZZ", 
          "MessagePassword" => "ZZZZZZZ"
                          ]
                  ]
              ],
    "PackageRequest" =>
      [
        "ID" => "82346255"
      ],
    "ItineraryItems" =>
      [
        "ItineraryItem" =>
        [
          "Accommodation" => 
          [
            "DateRange Start" => "1/07/2011",
            "Duration" => "P10N", 
            "End" => "11/07/2011",
            "RoomProfiles" => 
            [
              "RoomProfile"=>
              [ 
                "RoomType" => "DBL",
                "RoomTypeCode" => "DBA4", 
                "Quantity" => "1",
                "PassengerRPHs" =>
                [
                  "ListOfPassengerRPH" => "1 2",
                ]
              ]
          ],
          "MealPlans" => 
          [
            "MealPlan Plan" => "AI",
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "PassengerListItems" => 
    [
      "PassengerListItem" => 
      [
        "RPH" =>"1", 
        "Code" => "10", 
      ],
    "PassengerListItem" => 
      [ 
        "RPH" => "2", 
        "Code" => "10"
      ]              
    ]
  ]
];

$response = $service->call('Presstours.TtiPackageCosting', $data);
return response()->json($response);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't provide any code showing how you are requesting the SOAP service.

```
$wrapper = new \Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\SoapWrapper();

$service = $wrapper->add('ServiceName', function ($service) {
    $service->wsdl('http://serviceurl')
            ->cache(WSDL_CACHE_NONE)
            ->trace(true);
});

$data = [
    // ...
];

$loginResponse = $service->call('ServiceName.someMethod', [$data]);
```

Bear in mind it will change according to the Soap service you're requesting and what you want to do.

Comment: GOTO THIS ERROR: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: That error comes when you perform any operation on an object which is null. Edit your question and add your code. Without reading your code, it's hard to imagine what it can be.

Comment: added function used in php

Comment: @wwhitewalter Are you sure you need to send all the $data ? Are you fetching data, aren't you? Anyway, try to pass your $data inside another array, like I did ([$data]).